# How do I refresh an element or specific part of my code at a preset time?

Tags: javascript, html, function, refresh, reload

I currently have this code which refreshes the whole html page. In my script, I managed to set it so that the page uses this function to refresh 10 minutes before each time value in my data array (which consists of a range of time values). However, this resets every element on my page. Is there any way I can refresh specific elements within my script, such as a div - without disrupting the others - at a preset time, for example 12:50pm every day?

```
function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds) {
    var now = new Date();
    var then = new Date();

    if(now.getHours() > hours ||
        (now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() > minutes) ||
        now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() == minutes && now.getSeconds() >= seconds) {
            then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
    }
    then.setHours(hours);
    then.setMinutes(minutes);
    then.setSeconds(seconds);

    var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime());
    setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, timeout);
}
```

Comment: You can calculate a difference between current time and time which you need and then set a timer.

Comment: @ya.ymer would I use setTimeout to do this?